# how to refer to an object variable as an arguemnt in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have multiple lists in a class. I want to get a total for an int argument in a function. I have 3 lists that have same variables, how can i refer to each one and add it to a total without many for each loops?

For example

```
public int getCalories(string name, ref int argument)
{
    int total = 0;
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        total += item.argument;
    }
    foreach (var item in list2)
    {
        total += item.argument;
    }
   foreach (var item in list3)
    {
        total += item.argument;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `list.Sum` ?..

Comment: `list1.Sum(item => item.argument) + list2.Sum(item => item.argument) +`  etc.

Comment: Can you show some sample data plus expected result? What is the relation (if any) between `ref int argument` and `item.argument`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your parameter name is used for, so you should remove it.

If your code above works, i think you can use linq' Sum method to get your result.
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-7.0

```
public int getCalories(ref int argument)
    => list.Sum(x => x.argument) + list2.Sum(x => x.argument) + list3.Sum(x => x.argument);
```

Comment: the argument ref int argument means that i want to refer to an object var , 
for example if my object is apple i want to refer to apple.name as an argument